# Как ускорить работу программы

Tags: python

Есть задача

Возвести число в степень и вывести остаток от деления результата на 1000000007

У меня такой код

```
n, p = input().split()
n = int(n)
p = int(p)
print((n ** p) % 1000000007)
```

На одном из тестов выдает Time limit. Как я могу оптимизировать код?

Comment: `pow(n, p, 1000000007)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

тут надо применить арифметику остатков

1. воспользоваться формулой `a^b mod c = (a mod c)^b mod c`

что это дает - не надо работать с чрезмерно большими основаниями

сравните скорость работы этих двух кодов:

```
n = 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 #int(n)
p = 111111
z = 1000000007

x = n % z

print((x**p) % z)
print((n**p) % z)
```

скорость отличается на порядок

2. аналогично можно воспользоваться формулой `a^b mod c = a^(b mod c - 1) mod c`

в итоге код будет таким:

```
x = n % z
y = p % (z - 1)

print(x**p % z)
```

если я не путаю конечно с п.2)

**P.S.**

1000000007 - простое число, но вроде в этой задаче этот факт никак не использовать

вот если бы надо было найти остаток от деления `n^1000000007` на `1000000007` то тут все было бы просто - малая теорема Ферма

Comment: Time limit все равно не проходит. Тот же самый тест(какой конкретно не знаю)

Comment: @chehmakin, тогда нужна 3 оптимизация - воспользоваться формулой `a^b mod c  = (a mod c)^b mod c`, т.е. надо пойти по логарифмическому пути - возводить в квадрат и вычислять остаток, возводить в квадрат и вычислять остаток и т.д., скорее всего если не проходит по времени, то задается высокая степень - вот ее и надо срезать таким путём

Answer (score 3):

[Возведение в степень по модулю](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E) - хорошо исследованная задача. Главная идея - после каждой арифметической операции брать результат по модулю. Тем самым арифметика работает с операндами ограниченной длины, то есть быстрее.

Вторая вещь которая ускоряет получение результата - [быстрое возведение в степень](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C).

Итоговый алгоритм имеет сложность `O(log(p))`, `p` - показатель степени. От основания степени время работы не зависит (почти, всё-таки основание надо прочитать и взять от него модуль). На практике это означает что степень считается быстрее чем производится считывание чисел из входного потока.

```
def mod_mul(mod, a, b):
    return (a * b) % mod


def mod_pow(mod, a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    if b == 1:
        return a
    if b % 2 == 0:
        p2 = mod_pow(mod, a, b // 2)
        return mod_mul(mod, p2, p2)
    return mod_mul(mod, a, mod_pow(mod, a, b - 1))


mod = 1000000007
n, p = map(int, input().split())
print(mod_pow(mod, n % mod, p))
```

> ```
> $ echo 1234567 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935 | python exponentiation-by-squaring.py
> 630926649
> ```

И как мне подсказали в комментарии, всё уже придумано до нас. В Python есть встроенная реализация модулярной экспоненты - [pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow):

```
n, p = map(int, input().split())
print(pow(n, p, 1000000007))
```

Comment: NB: В Python есть встроенная функция `pow` с тремя аргументами, которая это умеет.

Comment: Спасибо! Добавил в ответ.